# 2nd Notification for Rejected Sales Order

Tags: acumatica

We have an approval setup for all Sales Order. Whenever the Sales Order is in Pending Approval, the Approver has to approve the Sales Order. However, due to some reason if the Approver rejects the Sales Order, it sends out the Rejection Notification. After that the status of Sales Order changes back to Open.

Again, the user rectifies the Sales Order and status changes back to Pending Approval. The Approver rejects the Sales Order second time due to other reason.

However, this time the Rejection Notification has not been sent as it is already sent first time.

Any suggestion how I can make the changes or where I should be looking for so that it sends out the notification every time there is a Sales Order being rejected.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer,

You have to add LastModifiedField on the Summary and then in Automation Step. This will reset the notification status field and it will send the 2nd notification.